# Where can I purchase this "stuff" called neutral cure silicone rubber?

Tags: pcb, components, glue

I read your posting about the "What kind of glue should I use for PCB-mounted components to avoid vibrations?" and you mentioned that the "superb solution" was "neutral cure silicone rubber". Where can this be readily be purchased without having to buy cases of 48 or 144 etc. which was about all I could find "on line"?

Comment: The usage of quotes multiple times here is hilariously awesome.

Comment: you mean "hilariously awesome"

Answer (score 7):

Please cite URL of post referred to.
 What country are you in?

Neutral cure silicone rubber is made by a range of manufacturers and some have a range of products. It is readily available in single tube quantities in many countries (at least China, Hong Kong, USA and New Zealand in my experience and essentially certainly it will be available in the large majority of countries worldwide).

There are 2 main types (and quite a few more specialist types that you are less likely to encounter.)

- Oxime  cure are cheaper and  release methyl alcohol and oxime compounds which are not suitable for some uses. eg not for use with Polycarbonate plastic. Not ideal for large copper surfaces.
- Alkoxy release only Methyl Alcohol and are suitable for most uses.

If a nutral cure SR ddoes not say what type it is it will be Oxime.

The major silicone rubber suppliers internationally are Dow Corning & Shin Etsu (Japanese) with others such as Du Pont and similar not being disgraced.

Dow Corning sell Oxime "Neutral Plus" in Asia and some other areas but it tends to not be seen in the US.

Search ebay with
- neutral cure silicone
 for a range of products.[Examples](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_BIN=1&_nkw=neutral+cure+silicone&_trksid=p3286.c0.m301)

Diagram some only of Dow Cornings offerings.
 Orange = oxime.
 Blue = alkoxy.

[You MAY be able to buy DC products online here](https://www.xiameter.com/en/Products/Pages/ProductLanding.aspx)

[image]

Dow Corning

Comment: Is there a special silcon sealant for electronics vs. the stuff found in the hardware store? e.g [this](http://www.bunnings.com.au/selleys-310g-multipurpose-silicone-sealant_p1210386) says it's neutral (non-acid) curing

Comment: @tgun926 That should be acceptable - if it does not ssmell of acetic acid it is almost certainly Oxime neutral cure given the price and general tendency of manufacturers to do things cheaply. Oxime is somewhat corrosive on bare copper when not set (not usually a problem in practice) and probably not suitable for polycarbonate (some clear lenses etc). It is possible to vary general properties widely within a general description range - Dow Corning tend to know what they are doing and do it - anyone else may and may. I have met some mechanically very poor products (and some very good ones).